# Plugins in react markdown with next.js does not work

Tags: next.js, strapi, react-markdown

I have a project that uses next.js in the frontend and strapi in the backend.
For rendering the reach text of strapi that uses markdown, I use ReactMarkdown package version "6.0.3", in the frontend.

It works well - except the strikethrough and the underline.
For the strikethrough to work (for now it just render a text like that: ~~some text to delete~~), I need to add a plugin that called remarkgfm or gfm,
and for the underline - it just showing some text tag and not underline text, and for that to work I need to add a plugin that called rehype-raw.
thats from the documentation:

> Appendix A: HTML in markdown
> react-markdown typically escapes HTML (or ignores it, with skipHtml) because it is dangerous and defeats the purpose of this library.
> However, if you are in a trusted environment (you trust the markdown), and can spare the bundle size (±60kb minzipped), then you can use rehype-raw:

and that is because it is not translate html directly.

this is my code:

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import gfm from 'remark-gfm'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'


import style from './single-paragraph.module.scss'

const SingleParagraph = ( { subTitle, text, image, floatPosition } ) => {
  
  const styleRow = {display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'start'}
  const styleRowReverse = {display:'flex', flexDirection: 'row-reverse', alignItems: 'start'}
return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      {subTitle && <h3 className={style.sub_title}>{subTitle}</h3>}
      <div className={style.text_container}>
          <div style={floatPosition==='end' ? styleRow : styleRowReverse} className={style.flex}>
          {text &&
            <ReactMarkdown 
              className={style.text} 
              linkTarget={ (href) => href.startsWith('http') ? "_blank" : "_self" }
              remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} 
            >{text}</ReactMarkdown> 
          }
          {image && <img src={image.url} width={image.width} height={image.height} alt="image" className={style.img}/>}
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleParagraph
```

but then it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2')
```

I tried to add this to next.config.js as this discussion suggested
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25454
:

```
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  "react-markdown",
  "remark-gfm",
  "micromark-extension-gfm",
  "micromark-util-combine-extensions",
  "micromark-util-chunked",
  "micromark-util-character",
  "micromark-util-sanitize-uri",
  "micromark-util-encode",
  "micromark-util-classify-character",
  "micromark-util-resolve-all",
  "micromark-factory-space",
  "mdast-util-gfm",
  "ccount",
  "mdast-util-find-and-replace",
  "unist-util-visit-parents",
  "unist-util-is",
  "mdast-util-to-markdown",
  "markdown-table",
]);

module.exports = withTM({ webpack5: false });
```

and then in my file import markdown with:

```
import Markdown from 'react-markdown/react-markdown.min'
```

but is still gives that error,
what I am doing wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to your errors and I recognize you've attempted to leverage plugins to overcome your `ins` or `del` issues.

However, the [remark markdown processor](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark#) supports the [CommonMark specification](https://commonmark.org) which does not include support for `ins` or `del` tags. Presumably the [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#react-markdown) component and the plugins are subject to [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org) limitations:

1. [Why no underline?](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/why-no-underline/3130)
2. [Strikeout threw out?](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/strikeout-threw-out-strikethrough-strikes-out-throughout/820)